# Unable to add local package in pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Trying to add local package in flutter but getting error:

```
Error on line 42, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: Invalid version constraint: Could not parse version "path:../hello/". Unknown text at "path:../hello/".

   ╷
42 │     path:../hello/
   │     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
pub get failed (65;    ╵)
```

`pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter  

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0

  hello: 
    path:../hello/
```

I have tried to  indent the path with *tab* and *space* but no luck.

Comment: Did you really use `path:../hello/` or is it just an example?

Comment: hello is the name of plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pubspec.yaml` is really unforgiving about a missing whitespace. If you have confirmed the local package path correct, then the following is definitely an error:

```
hello: 
  path:../hello/
```

because you're missing a   after the `path:`.

Change it to the following:

```
hello: 
  path: ../hello/
```

hence `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter  

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0

  hello: 
    path: ../hello/
```